# Place text when you select inside a div when you select a radio button.

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have radio button inside accordion as follows:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion2" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab">
            <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne1">Collapsible Group 1</a></h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <i class="fa fa-laptop fa-4x turquoise" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>
                    <label class="automaticaBRK">
                        <input name="designLayout" type="radio" id="designLayout_0" form="businessCards" value="yes" checked><br>
                        Yes
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <i class="fa fa-laptop fa-4x orange" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>
                    <label class="automaticaBRK">
                        <input name="designLayout" type="radio" id="designLayout_1" form="businessCards" value="no"><br>No
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseTwo1">Collapsible Group 2</a></h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseTwo1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">Content for Accordion Panel 2</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseThree1">Collapsible Group 3</a></h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseThree1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">Content for Accordion Panel 3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The accordion heading are aligned to the left. And the radio button labeled "Yes" is checked in buy default. I want to the word Yes placed the div with class of "panel-heading" next to the h4 tag and aligned right. When you check the "No" radio button I want No to be there. How can I do this?

Comment: Can you place your code into something like a jsfiddle so we can see it working

Comment: What you exactly need is not clear so far. Are you looking for how to add an event listener of type on change to your checkboxes ? when checked put "No" inside a div ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though the question is not quite clear. But this is the code to get you the value of the checked radio button.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 //To show yes by default
  $("#text").html($('input[type="radio"]:checked').val());
  $('input[type="radio"]').on('click change', function(e) {
    $("#text").html(($(this).val()));
});
});
```

the `$('#text')` is the id of a div displaying the checked radio button value for demo.

Check Working [example](https://jsfiddle.net/dofot69z/11/)

Comment: Thank you. On default the Yes radio button is checked, so how can I have yes displayed on default?

Comment: Thank you very much. This is what I was looking for. Sorry I couldn't be clear.

Answer (score 0):

In your html the h4 column you can eidt it to include a span: It will make it align right

```
<h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2"            href="#collapseOne1">Collapsible Group 1</a><span id="reply" class="pull-right"></span></h4>.
```

And the following jquery should get the value from the begining and update it on change.

```
document.getElementById("reply").innerHTML = $("input[name=designLayout]:radio:checked").val();
$("input[name=designLayout]:radio").change(function () {         
    document.getElementById("reply").innerHTML = $(this).val();     
});
```